# Where is the event object created in a message producer in Otto?

Tags: android, otto, event-bus

Following the [code example for Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), when an event is produced, an event class is returned from the producer function:

```
@Produce public AnswerAvailableEvent produceAnswer() {
    // Assuming 'lastAnswer' exists.
    return new AnswerAvailableEvent(this.lastAnswer);
}
```

However, the `AnswerAvailableEvent` does not seem to be defined anywhere. The only other times it is mentioned in the documentation is when the event is posted

```
bus.post(new AnswerAvailableEvent(42));
```

and when the event is received:

```
@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(AnswerAvailableEvent event) { ... }
```

Is this class automagically defined somehow? how does the class know what to do with the `this.lastAnswer` parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this class automagically defined somehow?

No. It is something that you write, named whatever you want, holding onto whatever event data that you want.

> how does the class know what to do with the this.lastAnswer parameter?

That is a constructor parameter. When you write your event class, you can implement whatever constructors make sense to you.